# Writing an instance without forcing a dependency

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to write an instance without forcing a dependency. Lets say I'm creating package `B`, which doesn't depend on package `A`, nor does package `A` depend on package `B`. However, package `B` contains data type, and package `A` a class, of which it would be useful to have `B` as an instance of `A`.

But other than that type/instance relation, `A` and `B` are completely independent, and it's perfectly reasonable to use one without the other.

Is there a way to set up a package and define such an instance without using orphan instances?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the orphan instance. I don't think you can avoid it. It is by definition a class instance in a module that does not contain the type it is instanciated with

Comment: You could probably have some cpp flags that activate the instance optionally in package A

Comment: The horrifying nature of orphan instances is the primary reason that `profunctors`, and therefore `lens` have so many dependencies. There is no way at present for a module or package to specifically bless an instance in another module or package. Edward Kmett has a package notion and I have a module notion for how such blessing could work, but apparently there are complications with such things as the behemoth backpack project, which I don't understand myself.

Comment: Orphan instances lead to really *nasty* problems where incoherence can go undetected, and where small changes can cause code not to compile anymore. I could be wrong, but I believe undetected incoherence can even lead to type safety failures, segmentation faults, and similar fun.

Answer (score 3):

Your options are to have one package depend on the other; create a third package with just the types and have both packages depend on that; create a third package that depends on both packages and has orphan instances.

The first and the third option are the only ones available if you don't control both packages (or can't convince the developer of the one you don't control to make the needed changes).

The third option requires orphan instances, but is slightly less bad than normal orphan instances, because it would be the "authoritative" choice.  The third option is [fairly common](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=instances).